# Finding where a function is not analytic

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Using the principal branch, find all points where $$\frac{z^{1/3}}{z^2 -4}$$ is NOT analytic. All I can think of is $z=2,-2$ but how can I find other points? How do I test for bring analytic if I can't separate into real and imaginary parts?

Comment: The factor $z^{1/3}$ is multi-valued were you given a definition for it? For example one of its branches.

Comment: You forgot $z = 0$ and all the other points of the branch cut where $z^{1/3}$ and hence $\frac{z^{1/3}}{z^2-4}$ isn't even continuous. $f(z)$ is complex differentiable at $z=a$ iff $f(z) = f(a)+C\ (z-a)+o(|z-a|)$ where by definition $C = f'(a)$.

Comment: @Hellen yes, using the principal branch.

Comment: Then, the points in which they cut that principal branch are also problematic, the function will be even discontinuous there.

Comment: Right, but how am I certain that these are all of the points?

Comment: @RyanGoulden To know that you found all the points, just use that the product of functions differentiable (analytic) in a point is differentiable in that point.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you also need to be concerned about branch cuts of the logarithm, since $z^{1/3}=\exp(1/3\log z)$
$$
\frac{z^{1/3}}{z^2-4}=\frac{\exp(1/3\log z)}{z^2-4}
$$
With the principal branch cut on the negative reals as well, the function in the numerator is not analytic (or continuous).

Comment: The principal branch cut is $(-\infty,0]$ so it is analytic elsewhere (except a few poles)

Comment: Doesn't that depend on who you ask? I.e there are choices for which branch cut you choose

Comment: The principal branch of $\log (z)$ is the one analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$ and $\log (1) = 0$, ie. $\log(z)  =\int_1^z \frac{1}{s} ds$ where the path $1 \to z$ is contained in $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$. You can define many other branches but they are not the called principal branch.

Comment: @reuns fair enough, that makes sense. I am editing.